# Boundary regularity for elliptic PDE in Lipschitz domains

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-pde, regularity

In section 2.6 of Fernandez-Real and Ros-Oton's book "Regularity theory for elliptic PDEs" it is stated that solutions of the Dirichlet problem with smooth data for the Laplacian are

1. $C^{1-s}(\bar \Omega)$ for any $s>0$ in domains $\Omega$ with $C^1$ boundary.
2. $C^{\gamma}(\bar \Omega)$ for some $\gamma>0$ depending on the Lipschitz constant of the Lipschitz domain $\Omega$.

They don't prove these results but cite books by Krylov "Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Hölder Spaces" and Kenig "Harmonic Analysis Techniques for Second Order Elliptic Boundary Value Problems". I've found Lemma 1.2.4 in the second book which gives a sketch of the proof but does not give much details on the constants.

Does anybody know whether one can make $\gamma$ arbitrarily close to $1$ by making the domain flatter (smaller Lipschitz constant)? I am also interested in variable (smooth) coefficients operators. I understand that in the latter case, the Holder regularity exponent must also depend on the ellipticity of the operator but also wonder if this dependence is continuous.